# Wordpress - email users when their posts liked by the other users

Tags: php, wordpress, email, author

I'm using " [simple like system](https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System) " Plugin, I have this function to check when users get post liked by the other users, How can i send an email to post author when his posts got liked by the others?

Something like " Hey {Post Author name}, {username of who likes the post} liked your post {post title}" { Post permalink}, visit {username} Profile at {author url}.

```
/**
 * Utility to test if the post is already liked
 * @since    0.5
 */
function already_liked( $post_id, $is_comment ) {
    $post_users = NULL;
    $user_id = NULL;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // user is logged in
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $post_meta_users = ( $is_comment == 1 ) ? get_comment_meta( $post_id, "_user_comment_liked" ) : get_post_meta( $post_id, "_user_liked" );
        if ( count( $post_meta_users ) != 0 ) {
            $post_users = $post_meta_users[0];
        }
    } else { // user is anonymous
        $user_id = sl_get_ip();
        $post_meta_users = ( $is_comment == 1 ) ? get_comment_meta( $post_id, "_user_comment_IP" ) : get_post_meta( $post_id, "_user_IP" ); 
        if ( count( $post_meta_users ) != 0 ) { // meta exists, set up values
            $post_users = $post_meta_users[0];
        }
    }

    if ( is_array( $post_users ) && in_array( $user_id, $post_users ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} // already_liked()
```

this one for post user likes

```
/**
 * Utility retrieves post meta user likes (user id array), 
 * then adds new user id to retrieved array
 * @since    0.5
 */
function post_user_likes( $user_id, $post_id, $is_comment ) {
    $post_users = '';
    $post_meta_users = ( $is_comment == 1 ) ? get_comment_meta( $post_id, "_user_comment_liked" ) : get_post_meta( $post_id, "_user_liked" );
    if ( count( $post_meta_users ) != 0 ) {
        $post_users = $post_meta_users[0];
    }
    if ( !is_array( $post_users ) ) {
        $post_users = array();
    }
    if ( !in_array( $user_id, $post_users ) ) {
        $post_users['user-' . $user_id] = $user_id;
    }
    return $post_users;
} // post_user_likes()
```

Here is what i tried to do but the whole function stopped working and email not sent.

I added do_action and add_action, I don't know why but i saw another snippet did that.

Original function above!!

```
function already_liked( $post_id, $is_comment ) {
    $post_users = NULL;
    $user_id = NULL;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // user is logged in
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $post_meta_users = ( $is_comment == 1 ) ? get_comment_meta( $post_id, "_user_comment_liked" ) : get_post_meta( $post_id, "_user_liked" );
        if ( count( $post_meta_users ) != 0 ) {
            $post_users = $post_meta_users[0];
        }
    } else { // user is anonymous
        $user_id = sl_get_ip();
        $post_meta_users = ( $is_comment == 1 ) ? get_comment_meta( $post_id, "_user_comment_IP" ) : get_post_meta( $post_id, "_user_IP" ); 
        if ( count( $post_meta_users ) != 0 ) { // meta exists, set up values
            $post_users = $post_meta_users[0];
        }
    }

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_url = get_author_posts_url( $user_id );
    $recipient = get_userdata($post_users);
    $recipient_email = $recipient->user_email;
    $body = sprintf('%s Liked your post!'. "\n\n", $user->display_name );
    $body .= sprintf( 'Visit Artist Page: %s', $user_url );
    wp_mail( $recipient_email , 'New Likes!', $body );

    add_action('post_like_user', $user_id, $post_users );

    if ( is_array( $post_users ) && in_array( $user_id, $post_users ) ) {

            do_action( 'post_like_user', $user_id, $post_users );

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
} // already_liked()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the fact that it looks like that you are using Wordpress, I can advise you to use the default e-mail tool in Wordpress.

```
wp_mail( string|array $to, string $subject, string $message, string|array $headers = '', string|array $attachments = array() );
```

Reference: (Developer Resources) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @Koen, I'm still newbie with Wordpress and I tried more times to create this function but i fail, Can you help me please..

Comment: No i didn't get any errors, Let me update my question of what i did, and i appreciate your help, Thanks.

Comment: Hello bro @Koen, I updated my question, Kindly take a look, Thanks.

Comment: Hello bro @KoenHollander, any hope to give me a real answer of how to make it work, I still newbie with wp, and I updated me question,Thanks.